# Is there a way to send a GET request in an API endpoint for xlsx for the vuejs to use?

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework

I've already set up an endpoint that returns a specific data based on the DateFilter that I've created. And when Using the **?format=xlsx** it downloads an xlsx file with the list of specific data based on the DateFilter that was requested. I'm also done on the search function in the frontend by passing the url in the searchCarriers, the only thing missing now is to have a downloadable xlsx in the frontend. How can I do this?

This is my DateFilter

```
class CarrierFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    date_app_rec__gte = DateFilter(field_name='date_app_rec', lookup_expr='gte')
    date_app_rec__lte = DateFilter(field_name='date_app_rec', lookup_expr='lte')
    date_sample_rec__gte = DateFilter(field_name='date_sample_rec', lookup_expr='gte')
    date_sample_rec__lte = DateFilter(field_name='date_sample_rec', lookup_expr='lte')
    date_of_qca__gte = DateFilter(field_name='date_of_qca', lookup_expr='gte')
    date_of_qca__lte = DateFilter(field_name='date_of_qca', lookup_expr='lte')
    date_created__gte = DateFilter(field_name='date_created', lookup_expr='gte')
    date_created__lte = DateFilter(field_name='date_created', lookup_expr='lte')
    patient_name = CharFilter(field_name='patient_name', lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = Carrier
        fields = ('date_app_rec__gte', 'date_app_rec__lte', 
                'date_sample_rec__gte', 'date_sample_rec__lte',
                  'date_of_qca__gte', 'date_of_qca__lte',
                  'date_created__gte', 'date_created__lte',
                  'patient_name',)
```

This is my ModelViewSet

```
class CarrierViewSet(XLSXFileMixin, ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Carrier.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CarrierSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,) #  for uploading of attachments
    filename = 'carrier-reports.xlsx'
    filter_class = (CarrierFilter)  # filtering From date and To date
    filterset_fields = ('patient_name', 'promo_code')
    search_fields = ('patient_name', 'promo_code', 'insurance_verified_tsg_verification')
```

This returns all the specific dates in the table in the frontend

```
searchCarriers: function () {
      // Search function
      api_url = `/api/v1/carrier/?date_app_rec__gte=${this.carrier_from_date_app_rec}&date_app_rec__lte=${this.carrier_to_date_app_rec}&date_sample_rec__gte=${this.carrier_from_date_sample_rec}&date_sample_rec__lte=${this.carrier_to_date_sample_rec}&date_of_qca__gte=${this.carrier_from_date_of_qca}&date_of_qca__lte=${this.carrier_to_date_of_qca}&date_created__gte=${this.carrier_from_date_created}&date_created__lte=${this.carrier_to_date_created}&patient_name=${this.carrier_search_patient_name}`
      this.searching = true;
      this.$http.get(api_url)
        .then((response) => {
          this.carriers = response.data;
          this.searching = false;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          this.searching = false;
          console.log(err);
        })
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can request URL as you do by using `GET` 
but you have to take care of what are you doing

**Front-end Side:** 
Using [download](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes) attribute

```
 this.$http.get(api_url)
    .then((response) => {
     let a= document.createElement('A')
     a.href= response.data
     a.download = true
     document.body.appendChild(a)
     a.click()
    }
```

if you don't want to appear you can manage by CSS `display:none` or `opacity:0`

**Back-end Side:**

you have to add to the data or the link you provide as response Header [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)

```
Content-Disposition: 'attachment'  // for example
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, I've already created a function in my js file same as the url in my searchCarriers. Should I put the function in the v-on:click.prevent? I've used the a href with download in it. But for some reason; It downloads the whole page.

Comment: because you have to add to the `a` href the url for the data you want to download instead of `.html` page

Comment: So, you mean that I'll have to pass the API endpoint in the href with the ?formar=xlsx? If that's what you meant, I've already done it but i-redirects me right to the API.